# Unskew a rectangle picture that's inclined and a rombus shape

Tags: python, opencv, alignment

Hello I have some question is related to correct license plate image alignment. I already have searched in google, but I still cannot find the answer code.

Now, for I solve this problem, using  python, opencv.

I have a license plate image that is skewed, inclined, or diagonal like below.
[image: [enter image description here]

So, I want these images to align and "un-skew".

If you have some code, Would you mind share for me?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use [geometric_transformations](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_geometric_transformations/py_geometric_transformations.html#affine-transformation)

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
# load image
img = cv2.imread('4llcP.png')
rows,cols,ch = img.shape
# cornerpoints of plate
pts1 = np.float32([[64,29],[533,120],[34,318]])
# new positions of points
pts2 = np.float32([[0,0],[cols-30,0],[0,rows-30]])
# transform image
M = cv2.getAffineTransform(pts1,pts2)
dst = cv2.warpAffine(img,M,(cols,rows))
# show image
cv2.imshow('Res',dst)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I have lots of random license plate image. So, I cannot use specific location. I need some codes for random plate images. Thankyou!

Comment: OP, have you found any solution to this?